# Unexpected text found in layout file?

Tags: android

this is my first poste here: :)

I was trying to write an app. I'm absolutely new to writing apps. I pasted a SneekBar in my content_main. After that I wanted to write the code for it in my activity_main.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

int progress;

public void onProgressChanged (SeekBar seekBar, int progresValue, boolean fromUser){
SeekBar

}

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I stopped to write when I saw this:

[image]

When I press F1 as it shows Google comes up with Error 404.
I'm Using Android Studio 3.3 Canary 8.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you write java code in xml file. this cause an error.
you want to create a progress bar ?? or something else?
this is not the right way to write code in android.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking at this for 2 Hours, After that you cant See clear :D

Answer (score 0):

The XML file is used to design layout here. Declare your methods inside your Activity class. In your case it is MainActivity.java, which is in app->Java->(Your Package name)->MainActivity.java. I suggest you to watch some basics.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking at this for 2 Hours, After that you cant See clear :D